# Is it possible to filter desktop icons

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have multiple screens and typically a lot of icons sat on them. Is there a way to filter this in a similar way to file search facility without going into explorer?

I would like say, to enter **.docx** into a textbox and have the desktop only display files with that extension.

Is this possible out of the box or with a 3rd party tool?

Comment: As I know, there is no way to do so, only can use search function in File Explorer and select the target is your Desktop.

Comment: Instead of storing those files directly on the desktop put them in a folder. You would open the explorer anyway and if you need the search it's likely that they're too many to keep track of anyway.

Comment: Why are you keeping all your shortcuts on your desktop? It's like having every file in your office on your desk instead of in filing cabinets where they belong ...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possibly to do a sub search using the desktop.

The search would have to be done through the windows explorer, or a 3rd party application that was designed for that specific task.

The closest thing to it is a quick search in the menu, but that is not limited to only searching your desktop.